# Why am I unable to edit a file on a windows share (cifs)?

Tags: permissions, fstab, cifs

I am mounting a Windows network drive to my Ubuntu machine and I am getting write permission errors when trying to edit a file.

```
sudo mount -t cifs
```

gives me

```
//MEDIASERVER/A on /home/anon/Media/Overflow/A type cifs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
```

and my fstab line is:

```
//MEDIASERVER/A /home/anon/Media/Overflow/A cifs username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD,mode=0777,dir_mode=07‌​77 0 0
```

Comment: If you get write permission errors when editing a file, it just looks like you don't have write permissions. I would check the server first, not the client.

Comment: Checked...write permissions are fine. I can connect to them on other computers and write to them just fine

Comment: Where is the write error?

Comment: I am trying to edit a file in python, but I can't even open the file in gedit and write to it. Even if I run it as root. I'm not sure if my fstab line is correct or what, but after a whole lot of searching, I gave up. I have admin rights on both machines, I just can't seem to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

You mode and dir_mode are wrong.  They are not permissions, but masks, (see man umask) or the man page for mount concerning mode:
    mode=value
              Set the mode of all files to value & 0777 disregarding the original permissions.  Add search permission to directories that have read permission.  The value is given in octal.
Either set it to something reasonable like 022 or just use 0.